# What is the best practice for pushing variables to templates?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm writing a web application and was wondering what the best practice is for pushing variables to templates. Right now, I'm requesting the models in my views and then pushing these objects to templates.

Example:

I have a framework and controls attached to these frameworks. If I want to display all the controls for the specific frameworks I would do this.

Models:

```
# models.py
class Framework(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)


class Control(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    framework = models.ForeignKey(Framework,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name="related framework")
    category = models.ForeignKey(FrameworkCat,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             verbose_name="related category",
                             null=True)
```

In views:

```
# views.py
def show_frameworks(request):
    frameworks = Framework.objects.all()
    controls = Control.objects.all()

    data['frameworks'] = frameworks
    data['controls'] = controls

   return render(request, 'show_frameworks.html', data)
```

And then in templates:

```
# templates/show_frameworks.html
<div>
{% for framework in frameworks %}
    <p>{{framework.name}}</p>
    {% for control in controls %}
        {% if control.framework == framework %}
            <p>{{control.title}}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Would this be efficient to do or would it be faster/more efficient to do something like this:

```
# views.py
def show_frameworks(request):
    controls = Control.objects.all().order_by('framework')

    data['controls'] = controls

   return render(request, 'show_frameworks.html', data)
```

And then in templates:

```
# templates/show_frameworks.html
<div>
{% for control in controls %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <p>{{control.framework.name}}</p>
        <p>{{control.title}}</p>
        {% with prevframework = control.framework %}
    {% else %}
        {% with curframework = control.framework %}
        {% if curframework != prevframework %}
            <p>{{control.framework.name}}</p>
            <p>{{control.title}}</p>
       {% else %}
            <p>{{control.title}}</p>
       {% endif %}
    {% with prevframework = control.framework %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

This looks a bit more complex but would mean I'd have to send less queries to the database and send data to the template. This is a simple example, but in my web application I have a pretty big database on a slow hosting so any time optimization is welcome. My question basically here is: would the latter be more efficient because only one for-loop is used and only one query is send to the database? Or is the former still more efficient, despite using two for-loops, looping over every control multiple times and sending two queries to the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move as much of the logic as possible to the DB/plain Python.

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which fetches the related `controls` for each `framework` and does the joining in plain Python. Don't put too much in the template as the template engine is relatively slower than plain Python and your code is less maintainable if you have too much:

```
def show_frameworks(request):
    frameworks = Framework.objects.prefetch_related('control_set').all()
    data['frameworks'] = frameworks
    return render(request, 'show_frameworks.html', data)
```

---

And then:

```
<div>
{% for framework in frameworks %}
    <p>{{framework.name}}</p>
    {% for control in framework.control_set %}
         <p>{{control.title}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I did not know about prefetch and select_related(). Thanks! However, I do not have a FK to controls on my framework model. The control model does have a FK to framework on it, because this is a many-to-one relationship. Added my models to the main post. How would your above example change?

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans I've updated the answer. Django adds a `<fieldname>_set` to the related object by default.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Marked as answered. Thanks!